# Microsoft edge remote debugging

Tags: remote-debugging, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to remotely debug a mobile web app in a W10&Edge phone from a computer through a USB connection? I mean, the same way we debug web apps in Android and iOS through Chrome and Safari dev tools.

If it is posible, which are the requirements of the computer? Would it be posible from a W7 or W8 computer?

Comment: Visual studio supports remote USB debugging, and web apps (uwp javascript apps)
you'll need a developer license though
depending on your app, it might not be too difficult to quickly convert it to a uwp app

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible via USB, but you can use something like [VorlonJS](http://www.davevoyles.com/creating-and-debugging-hosted-web-apps-with-manifoldjs-and-vorlonjs/) to debug websites remotely, even on mobile devices.

I demo exactly how to do this in a [sample on GitHub.](https://github.com/DaveVoyles/VorlonJSDemoSite)

**Developer:**

Simply navigate to your dashboard at h*ttp://vorlondebugger.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/default.* This is your dashboard for viewing who is currently on the Vorlon demo site.

**Users:**

Instruct them to navigate to *http://vorlondemoapp.azurewebsites.net/*, which is a basic HTML5 boilerplate site.

**Usage:**

Look at your dashboard, and you'll now see that the users are viewing the page. You can alter their code on-the-fly.

Comment: I already knew VorlonJS and it's a great tool for basic debugging actions such as DOM inspecting but I think it's far from chrome dev tools in terms of Javascript debugging. I was looking for a direct debugging tool, and as you say, it doesn't seem to exist such a tool yet.

Comment: Ah yes, in terms of JavaScript, I really don't know :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a same question. But I solve my problem with this:

I copied html+js code into my UWP application and then I can remote debug it with Visual Studio